# Error installing tkhtmlview: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mod3tiu\tkhtmlview_ee8ccc0ae66c418097da6559a8535704\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          import tkhtmlview
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mod3tiu\tkhtmlview_ee8ccc0ae66c418097da6559a8535704\tkhtmlview\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from tkhtmlview import html_parser
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mod3tiu\tkhtmlview_ee8ccc0ae66c418097da6559a8535704\tkhtmlview\html_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
          import requests
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Previously there was a problem with setup.py, latest  versions on pypi should not have this issue.  (I'm the author and maintainer of tkhtmlview)

Comment: Meaning can work on older version not latest version of Python3.xx. You will have wait on next two version.